# C#, AutoMapper, HOWTO: Map List to DataTable

Tags: datatable, automapper, enterprise-library, idatareader, table-valued-parameters

Due to working with enterprise library data blocking to execute stored procedures with Table valued params (TVP).

I want to be able to map a list => DataTable before the stored procedure execution.

The Problem is that I need to perform this conversion with AutoMapper and not manually.

I wish to do something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MyObject, IDataReader>()
    .ForMember
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: I don't think that automapper is the right tool for the job here.

Comment: @EfiBN For you previous question:

        var alphabet = 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z'.split(',');
        function generate(size, prefix, arr) {
            alphabet.forEach(function(letter) {
                if(size === 1) {
                    arr.push(prefix + letter);
                } else {
                    generate(size - 1, prefix + letter, arr);
                }
            });
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you need is something like Dapper instead of AutoMapper:

https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net